# Scale ticklabels

Tags: tikz-pgf, ticks, scale

How can I scale the ticklabels in Tikz to replicate the Matlab command

```
set(gca, 'XTick', xt, 'XTickLabel', xt.^3)
```

As an example, the xtick labels should be converted to the following

```
xtick={10,15,20,25,30,35},
xticklabels={1000,3375,8000,15625,27000,42875},
```

I want to have an automated procedure for this. Something like this:

```
xticklabel={$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick^3}$}
```

Sadly, tikz can not parse this...

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `xticklabel={\pgfmathparse{\tick^3}$\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}$}` as in the following example. If you have huge numbers, you might want to use `fpu`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xticklabel={\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}\pgfmathparse{\tick^3}$\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}$}]
\addplot [domain=0:35] {x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I replace your domain from "domain=0:8" to "domain=0:35", I get dimensions too large, how can I solve this?

Comment: @user2978680 I added instructions for that case.